# swift, ios: change size of view after orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

There're two views UITableView and UIView. I'm having a problem trying to change size of the views after changing orientation from portrait (70% : 30%) to landscape (0% : 100%). UITableView is on the top, UIView - at the bottom.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var graphView: GraphView!

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            //tableView : graphView = 0% : 100%
            tableView.frame.size.height = 0
            graphView.frame.size.height = size.height
            graphView.frame.size.width = size.width
        } else {
            //tableView : graphView = ~70% : ~30%
            tableView.frame.size.height = size.height - 250
            graphView.frame.size.height = 250
            graphView.frame.size.width = size.width
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - do not make any calculations based on device orientation. Make your calculations based solely on the new size.

Comment: I get new size from viewWillTransition method and set view's size based on the new size. What's the problem with that?

Comment: But you are deciding the layout based on `UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape`. Don't ever do that. Look at the new width and height of `size` to decide which layout to use. Your approach will fail on iPads when using the multitasking feature. This is why Apple removed the whole `interfaceOrientation` features from UIViewController.

Comment: How to do that? The idea is to choose element in table in portrait orientation and to show graph at the bottom; if device orientation has changed to landscape - then only the graph should be seen.

Comment: `if size.width > size.height { // "landscape"`.

Comment: That doesn't really change much. if size.height > size.width { //isPortrait
            tableView.frame.size.height = size.height - 250
            graphView.frame.size.height = 250
            graphView.frame.size.width = size.width
        } else { //isLandscape
            tableView.frame.size.height = 0
            graphView.frame.size.height = size.height
            graphView.frame.size.width = size.width
        }

Comment: My comments were about a secondary issue in your code. They have no bearing on your primary issue in your question.

Comment: What problem exactly are you having? Does the if statement behave correctly (by debugging) when you change orientation? Or is about the size that you have an issue, if so, which is the view you are having issues? Can you also post other part of your code where you manipulate those two views or the container (if any) containing them? Can you also post codes in viewDidAppear, viewDidLoad, viewDidLayoutSubviews.. just to be sure we didn't omit anything?